# Which Gradle property to use to get where Gradle will store the generated APK?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I want to automate the generation of my APK. This could easily be done with Gradle task but I have to know where the Generated APK is located.

My Questions:

1. How do I get this location?
2. Can I change this location?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the generated apk is generally in `app/build/outputs/apk/[productFlavorName]`.

Comment: yes, you are right but this could change depending on the gradle version so I do not want to hardcode that value inside the gradle task. Is there a property which i could use?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the filelocation to your preferred location and add to build.gradle (Module one):-

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "{filelocation}-${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
    }
}
```

Comment: Well this would work too but as much as possible I would like to know what does gradle use by default or if thats ever possible

Comment: I think android studio provide you option to change the location and by default it uses the location specified in system apart from this what else option you require.

Answer (score 0):

In my case and I think in yours too - "/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/app/BUILD_TYPE_NAME/release/

This is a default path where Gradle saves generated apks. And as I know you can't change this path.